# Exclude read time out from @Retryable annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I have a retryable REST call which retries on specific cases. Currently, it retries even on read timeout & connection timeout scenario as well.

```
@Retryable(value = {RestClientException.class},maxAttempts = 2,
        exclude = {HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest.class})
public ResponseEntity<String> testMethod() throws Exception {
    return restTemplateRtp.exchange("http://localhost:8080/api/test", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
}
```

In case of a readtimeout, the retry retries for 2 times, and then fails with this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error 
on POST request for "http://localhost:8080/api/test": Read timed 
out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I dont want to retry on read timeout but want the retry to continue for connect timeout. When I try to add `SocketTimeoutException` in the `exclude`, its still retrying for read timeout as well.

How to handle this scenario? I cant add `ResourceAccessException` to the `exclude`, then both the read & connect timeouts will stop getting retried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception stack trace i can say the `ResourceAccessException` is top level exception that is thrown due to underlying `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`.

and, from the [java-docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) socket timeout will be thrown on multiple use cases

> Signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept.

If would suggest adding custom logic for excluding any underlying exceptions

```
@Retryable(value = {RestClientException.class},maxAttempts = 2,
    exclude = {HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest.class})
public ResponseEntity<String> testMethod() throws Exception {

try {
     return restTemplateRtp.exchange("http://localhost:8080/api/test", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

    }catch(ResourceAccessException ex) {

      if(ex.getCause() instanceOf java.net.SocketTimeoutException 
           && ex.getCause().getMessage().equals("Read timed out")) {
            //exclude don't retry and return something
         }
         // else throw ex;

     }
    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some time-out processing logic：

```
@Retryable(value = {RestClientException.class},maxAttempts = 2,
            exclude = {HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest.class})
    public ResponseEntity<String> testMethod() throws Exception {
        try {
            return restTemplateRtp.exchange("http://localhost:8080/api/test", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // when timed out, what to do
        }
    }
```